# Where is the api key for AWS Amplify stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm new to AWS Amplify. I'm using AWS amplify Datastore in my react native frontend to do query, update and create mutations from the frontend. I can see that I use 'api-key' as the default authorization in graphql api settings page, But I can't find this api key in the frontend. I want to know where this api key is stored in frontend and how to prevent exposing it and how can I use another authorization instead of api-key to increase security ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find it in `aws-exports.js`:

```
import awsConfig from '../aws-exports';
const authToken = awsConfig.aws_appsync_apiKey;
```